# python list of dicts - convert each key-value as a individual dict

Tags: python, list-comprehension

with a list like below that has one or more dicts

`l = [{'b': 'h', 'c': (1,2)}, {'d': [0, 1], 'e': {'f': 2, 'g': 'i'} }  ]`

need to extract each key-value pair as an individual dict

Expected output

`[{'b': 'h'}, {'c': (1,2)}, {'d': [0, 1]}, {'e': {'f': 2, 'g': 'i'} }  ]`

I have been trying to do this via list comprehension - the outer comprehension could be something like `[ {k,v} for k, v in ??` - need some help in getting the inner comprehension.

Comment: What do you want to happen if two different dictionaries have the same key? Eg., `l = [{'b': 'h', 'c': (1,2)}, {'b': [0, 1]}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for - except that the order of the elements might be different, but that's to be expected when dealing with dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'b': 'h', 'c': (1,2)}, {'d': [0, 1], 'e': {'f': 2, 'g': 'i'}}]
[{k: v} for d in lst for k, v in d.items()]

=> [{'c': (1, 2)}, {'b': 'h'}, {'e': {'g': 'i', 'f': 2}}, {'d': [0, 1]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```py
[{k: v} for i in l for k, v in i.items()]
```